# Print variables, excluding ones that are zero

Tags: java

Let's say I have five int variables that are prompted for user input. User keys in the five value and two of those values are 0. I would like to ONLY print out values that are greater than zero.

```
int v1 = 1;
int v2 = 30;
int v3 = 0;
int v4 = 37;
int v5 = 0;
```

I would like to write a dynamic print statement that would exclude the int variables with Zero value.

Currently, my print statement displays all values:

```
System.out.printf("%s %d%n%s %d%n%s %d%n%s %d%n%s %d%n","V1;","v1","V2:","v2","V3:","v3","V4:","v4","V5:","v5");
```

I tried writing `if`-`else` statements but that became very cumbersome.

Comment: I have removed the JavaScript tag, as it seems unrelated.

Comment: When you have a series of variables distinguished by numbers, you probably should be using an array or list.

Comment: Same for the [tag:c] tag. Please don't add irrelevant tags to your question, as this can increase risk of the question's being closed or down-voted.

Comment: When you say 'zero' i suspect you are referring to the number 0 and not null value? - number 0 is still a valid number :)

Comment: Use `printf` to print.  Use `if then else` to do conditional.  Make your code simple and straightforward.  At this point, don't try to get clever with your code.

Comment: I never mentioned "null value(s)" in my question. @MaciejCygan

Comment: @SirSupernova - just checking, sometimes people confuse the two

Comment: @stark, not trying to get clever, trying to learn how to write the print statement using if-else however it becomes cumbersome as mentioned. Can you post an example that would be helpful? Thx

Comment: Write a function named `printIfNotZero`.  Then just call it on your 5 variables.  Now you just have 1 if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new method `printNonZeroVars(Integer... ints)`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int v1 = 1;
  int v2 = 30;
  int v3 = 0;
  int v4 = 37;
  int v5 = 0;
  printNonZeroVars(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)
}

public void printNonZeroVars(int... ints) {
  for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
     if (ints[i] > 0) {
          System.out.printf("V%d%d%n", i, ints[i]);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to box them to `Integer`, just declare the parameter as `int... ints`.

Comment: @DavidConrad Good catch, changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array. 
Iterate over the array and with an if you can check whether your current value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

So a simple way of achieving this would be to use some sort of Array/List.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>()
// Or as pointed out by David a better way would be to declare the list as
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(5);
list.add(1);
list.add(0);
....
```

Once you have the list you can use a loop to loop through the list and do relevant checks - something like this

```
String str = "";
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
   if(list.get(i) == 0) {
       continue;
   } 
   str += "v"+i + ":" + Integer.toString(list.get(i));
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Its pseudo but should give you a good head start :)

Comment: You should declare your lists as `List<Integer>`, not `ArrayList<Integer>`. [Program to the interface, not the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface/384067). And there's no need to repeat the generic type on the right-hand side; you can just write `new ArrayList<>()`. There's also no need to explicitly call `Integer.toString`. You can just append the Integer to the String and its toString method will be called.

Comment: @DavidConrad indeed List is more appropriate. I always specify the right-hand side type (a habit I guess).